# How to Set EndpointIPAddress in ordering subnet using java

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I set EndpointVlan in verifying Subnet IP.
This is my sample code to verify order. It returns Exceptions with message that Endpoint IP is required.

```
private void verifyStaticIp() {
    Long packageID = 0l; // ip item only (no sub-option)
    Long quantity = 1l;

    Price price = new Price();
    price.setId(12345l); // sample


    Property property = new Property(); // How to Set enpointVlanId in order template???
    property.setName("endPointVlanId");
    property.setValue("1223445");   

    // Create Order to verify
    Order packageOrder = new Order();
    packageOrder.setQuantity(quantity);
    packageOrder.setPackageId(packageID);
    packageOrder.getProperties().add(property);
    packageOrder.getPrices().add(price);

    try {
        Order order = com.softlayer.api.service.product.Order.service(client).verifyOrder(packageOrder);
        System.out.println("verify Static IP order result = " + order.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following java example:

```
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.network.Subnet;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.item.Price;

/**
 * Order a new static public Subnet. 
 * 
 * Important manual pages:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder/
 * 
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 */
public class createStaticPublicSubnet {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Your SoftLayer API username and key.
        String username = "set me";
        String apikey = "set me";

     // Declare item prices
        Long[] prices = { new Long(13983)};

        //The id of the IP address that you want to route a static subnet to.
        Long endPointIpAddressId = new Long(19868866);

        // The number of items to order
        Long quantity = new Long(1);

        String location = "AMSTERDAM";

        // The id of the SoftLayer_Product_Package you want to order.
        Long packageId = new Long(0);

        String containerIdentifier = "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Subnet";

        // Create a SoftLayer API client object
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);

        /*
         * Set up Order template
         */
        Subnet newOrder = new Subnet();
        newOrder.setContainerIdentifier(containerIdentifier);
        newOrder.setLocation(location);
        newOrder.setPackageId(packageId);
        newOrder.setQuantity(quantity);
        newOrder.setEndPointIpAddressId(endPointIpAddressId);

        // Add Item prices to list
        for (Long i : prices) {
            Price price = new Price();
            price.setId(new Long(i));
            newOrder.getPrices().add(price);
        }

        try 
        {
            Order orderResult = com.softlayer.api.service.product.Order.service(client).verifyOrder(newOrder);
            System.out.println("order successfully verified: " + orderResult);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
 }
}
```

#### Update 1.

Also, we can find the `“endPointIpAddressId”` through virtual Guest id, please see the example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[guest_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id, fullyQualifiedDomainName,primaryNetworkComponent[id,primaryIpAddress,primaryIpAddressRecord.id]]
Method: GET
```

The response should be something like this:

```
{
"fullyQualifiedDomainName": "hostnametest.test.com"
"id": 9054111
"primaryNetworkComponent": {
   "id": 4797111
   "primaryIpAddress": "119.81.111.111"
   "primaryIpAddressRecord": {
      "id": 24692446
  }-
}-
```

}

Where the value that we need to use to order the subnet is : `"id": 24692446`
Regards.

Comment: Thanks It works fine..:) but when I get the endpointIpAddressId, SL API returns null only. Let me post below how I implemented, but I found an alternative way to get the ID. Please check my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code to get EndPoindIpAddressID I've tried, but it returns nulls only.

```
private void getEndpointIP(){

    Account.Service accSrv = Account.service(client);

    accSrv.withMask().subnets().endPointIpAddress().id(); 
    accSrv.withMask().ipAddresses().endpointSubnets().endPointIpAddress().id();
    accSrv.withMask().publicSubnets().endPointIpAddress().id();

    Account acc = accSrv.getObject();

    List<Subnet> subnetList = acc.getPublicSubnets();

    for(Subnet sb  : subnetList){
        System.out.println("EndPoint IP : " + sb.getEndPointIpAddress());
        System.out.println("EndPoint IP ID : " + sb.getEndPointIpAddress().getId());
    }

}
```

}

This is an alternative way to get EndpointIpAddressId. Please Confirm if this is a valid implementation. Thank you~

```
private void getEndpointIP_altWay() {

    Account.Service accSrv = Account.service(client);

    accSrv.withMask().subnets().virtualGuests().fullyQualifiedDomainName();
    accSrv.withMask().subnets().virtualGuests().primaryIpAddress().id();
    accSrv.withMask().subnets().virtualGuests().status().name();
    accSrv.withMask().subnets().ipAddresses().ipAddress().id();

    Account acc = accSrv.getObject();

    for (Subnet sub : acc.getSubnets()) {

        List<Subnet> subnetList = acc.getPublicSubnets();

        for (Subnet sb : subnetList) {
            System.out.println("EndPoint IP : " + sb.getEndPointIpAddress());
            System.out.println("EndPoint IP ID : " + sb.getEndPointIpAddress().getId());
        }

        List<IpAddress> ipList = sub.getIpAddresses();

        List<Guest> gList = sub.getVirtualGuests();

        for (Guest gt : gList) {
            System.out.println(" name  : " + gt.getFullyQualifiedDomainName());
            System.out.println(" status  : " + gt.getStatus().getName());
            System.out.println(" public ip  : " + gt.getPrimaryIpAddress());

            for (IpAddress ip : ipList) {

                if (ip.getIpAddress().equals(gt.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
                    System.out.println(" endpoint ip id  : " + ip.getId());

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your example is ok, but it needs to add the id of `primaryIpAddressRecord`. This is a REST example to find the `“endPointIpAddressId”` through virtual Guest id : `https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[guest_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id, fullyQualifiedDomainName,primaryNetworkComponent[id,primaryIpAddress,primaryIpAddressRecord.id]]`.  I updated the same information in the answer. Please compare your results with this `Rest` request. I hope it help you.

Comment: I've checked EndpointIpAddressId is delivered as same as the value of your Rest example. Thank you for your help :)